# Photoshop saving for web issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have sliced up an image to save for web on Photoshop (for an e-newsletter) and it works fine on some computers but in others the sliced sections are visible - as in there are weird white lines and gaps on the image. How can I get rid of these?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this looks like (try linking to the image, instead of embedding it), but I understand that the output is an html file with a table of with sliced image.

Maybe you can try editing html code (by opening html file with a text editor) and adding `border=0` parameters to either `<img>` or `<table>` tags (i.e. `<table border=0 (...) >`).

Comment: im sending the thing through campaignmonitor and its when the email actually is sent that the problem arises. it may be an issue with them